# What am I missing? MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I am having this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tablename'(
'id'MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'content'TEXT NOT NULL,
'd' at line 1
```

From this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE 'tablename'(
'id'MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'content'TEXT NOT NULL,
'date_added' DATETIME NOT NULL,
'user' VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE ('id')
); ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Why?

Comment: Why are you using `MEDIUMINT` as your primary key? Is that single byte per row really that important?

Comment: It could possibly be important to him. However, that's not the question he's asking, so that point seems fairly irrelevant. Let him use the data types he wants, based on his preferences.

Comment: I'm just asking. 99% of the time it's someone being needlessly paranoid about disk space usage, and later gets bit when the number wraps, like when [Slashdot ran out of comment IDs](http://ardentdev.com/slashdot-ran-out-of-comments/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the backtick instead of the single quote (`'`). The backtick is this character:

```
`
```

Better yet - don't bother with either:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id MEDIUMINT ...
```

**Important**: also see the comments below from tadman; they round out this answer nicely by explaining the backticks and pointing out another syntax issue.

Comment: There's also an out of place `;` before the `ENGINE` definition.

Comment: Thanks @tadman - indeed there is! It was hard to see in that sea of quotes :)

Comment: To clarify, backticks are only required around column names that conflict with [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: @tadman they are also required if (for whatever reason) you are using a column name with a space in it such as ``Space Station``. Without the tick marks, this will throw an error in your dbms

Comment: Indeed, that too. Just remember, putting spaces in column names is a great way to irritate anyone working on your team.

Comment: Thanks a lot...It's been a long time since I used SQL for the last time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect notation.
In your create table statement, you are using the single quote ( ').
You can't use that here for table names and column names.
Alternatives would be the tick mark (`). Or just completely remove all notation altogether.

Here is your code, fully functional:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
`id` MEDIUMINT NOT NULL,
`content`TEXT NOT NULL,
`date_added` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`user` VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between the columnname and the type of the first two columns. Also, you have a ; to many at the end

```
CREATE TABLE 'tablename'(
'id' MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'content' TEXT NOT NULL,
'date_added' DATETIME NOT NULL,
'user' VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
UNIQUE ('id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```